# why can't I construct an std::span from iterators?

Tags: c++, iterator, c++20, std-span

Consider a large memory container. In this simple example an `std::vector<int>`:

```
std::vector v = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

[`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) allows me create a lightweight view over the memory. Now I want to simply print the span:

```
template<typename T>
void print(std::span<T> span) {
    std::cout << '[';
    if (span.size())
        std::copy(span.begin(), span.end() - 1, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));

    std::cout << span.back() << "]\n";
}

int main() {
    std::vector v = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    print(std::span{ v });
}
```

output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

---

now I want to make subsets (which is where the `std::span` actually becomes useful as a view). I can use iterators to specify my range and call [this constructor(3)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span/span) from `std::span`

```
template< class It, class End >
explicit(extent != std::dynamic_extent)
constexpr span( It first, End last );
```

But that doesn't work:

```
print(std::span{ v.begin() + 2, v.end() }); //error E0289
```

> C++ no instance of constructor matches the argument list            argument types are: (std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::conditional_t<true, std::_Simple_types, std::_Vec_iter_types<int, size_t, ptrdiff_t, int *, const int *, int &, const int &>>>>, std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::conditional_t<true, std::_Simple_types, std::_Vec_iter_types<int, size_t, ptrdiff_t, int *, const int *, int &, const int &>>>>)

---

there is the possibility of using the constructor(2) which takes a pointer and size:

```
print(std::span{ v.data() + 1, 3 }); //-> prints [1, 2, 3]
```

But that defeats the purpose of iterators.

**How can I construct an `std::span` using iterators? Am I missing something?**

---

full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <span>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T>
void print(std::span<T> span) {
    std::cout << '[';
    if (span.size())
        std::copy(span.begin(), span.end() - 1, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));

    std::cout << span.back() << "]\n";
}

int main() {
    std::vector v = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    print(std::span{ v.begin() + 2, v.end() });
}
```

---

until MSVC has implemented the constructor I will be using this `make_span` function:

```
template<typename It>
constexpr auto make_span(It begin, It end) {
    return std::span<std::remove_pointer_t<It::pointer>>(&(*begin), std::distance(begin, end));
}
```

---

*Using Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.7.5. Configuration: x64, Release. C++ Language Standard = /std:c++latest*

Comment: I'd blame an outdated standard library (this all very new, after all), given that GCC's is fine with it. LLVM's looks like it might also need a minute. [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/do7fPq)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can construct a `span` using iterators, it has [such a constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span/span) (as added by [P1394](https://wg21.link/p1394), which you can see in [[views.span]](http://eel.is/c++draft/views.span)):

```cpp
template< class It, class End >
explicit(extent != std::dynamic_extent)
constexpr span( It first, End last );
```

It's just that MSVC's standard library doesn't implement it. The program compiles fine on gcc, as expected.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense now, I am just confused why they are partially implementing constructors. Guess I will have to reside on a custom `make_span(first, last)` for now.