# Why does constructor of std::span does not limit the elements when constructed with 2 pointers/iterators

Tags: c++, c++20

```
#include <iostream>
#include <span>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>

namespace {
template <typename TSpan>
auto createSubSpan1(TSpan &, typename TSpan::iterator start,
                    typename TSpan::iterator stop) {
    static_assert(!std::is_convertible_v<typename TSpan::iterator, std::size_t>);
    return TSpan{start, stop};
}

template <typename TSpan>
auto createSubSpan2(TSpan &span, typename TSpan::iterator start,
                    typename TSpan::iterator stop) {
    auto startOffset = std::distance(span.begin(), start);
    auto stopOffset = std::distance(span.begin(), stop);
    std::cout << startOffset << "-" << stopOffset << std::endl;
    static_assert(!std::is_convertible_v<decltype(span.data() + startOffset), std::size_t>);
    return TSpan{span.data() + startOffset, span.data() + stopOffset};
}

template <typename TSpan>
auto createSubSpan3(TSpan &span, typename TSpan::iterator start,
                    typename TSpan::iterator stop) {
    return span.subspan(static_cast<size_t>(std::distance(span.begin(), start)),
                        static_cast<size_t>(std::distance(start, stop)));
}

template <typename TSpan>
auto printSpan(std::string_view header, TSpan span) {
    std::cout << header << std::endl;
    for (const auto &element : span) std::cout << "\t" << element << std::endl;
}
}  // namespace

int main() {
    int a[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
    auto span = std::span{a};

    std::vector<int> vector{11, 12, 13};

    auto beginIt = span.begin();
    auto endIt = std::move(vector.begin(), vector.end(), beginIt);

    printSpan("incorrect (iterator)", createSubSpan1(span, beginIt, endIt));
    printSpan("incorrect (pointer)", createSubSpan2(span, beginIt, endIt));
    printSpan("correct", createSubSpan3(span, beginIt, endIt));
}
```

[code at compiler-explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/oa8o99h3j)

In this code, I would expect the createSubSpan1/2 methods to call constructor (3) of https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span/span

```
template< class It, class End >
explicit(extent != std::dynamic_extent)
constexpr span( It first, End last );
```

However, for some reason both of them seem to print the complete span instead of the 3 elements I would expect. Variant 3 calling the subspan method does give the expected result.

Output of code with GCC, Clang and Clang+libc++:

```plaintext
incorrect (iterator)
    11
    12
    13
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
0-3
incorrect (pointer)
    11
    12
    13
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
correct
    11
    12
    13
```

As far as I can tell, both should be contiguous_iterator, the end iterator is a sized_sentinel_for the start iterator (as it is the same type), and conversion of the returned reference type of the iterator (int &) is the element type given the qualification conversion AND the iterator/pointer are not convertible to size_t (see static_assert).

So from everything I can deduce, the mentioned constructor should be chosen and give me the expected effect. Can you explain why it does not?

Related questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/64187250/2466431 : The answer indicates this constructor should work with GCC and Clang.

Comment: Shortly, you violate this rule in first two cases: http://eel.is/c++draft/span.cons#8.1 (`extent` is 9, while `last-first` is 3).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your example, the type of the `span` variable is `span<int, 9>`, so for `createSubSpan1/2()`, `TSpan` will be deduced as `span<int, 9>`, which guarantees that the returned span has `9` elements. In other words, you must ensure that `stop - start` is exactly `9`, otherwise you will get UB ([[span.cons#8]](https://eel.is/c++draft/span.cons#8)).

As for `createSubSpan3()`,  since `subspan()` returns `span<int, dynamic_extent>`, the number of elements of the constructed span is exactly `stop - start`.

Comment: k, so if `a` would have been a std::vector, this problem would not occur. Nor of the method uses std::span iso TSpan.

Comment: Sounds like a design flow in std::span that they even allow you to provide a size when not using dynamic_extend. Thanks for the answer, I did not realize that I was using a fixed size.